# Flex context menus don't allow "About" any more

Tags: apache-flex, contextmenu

We've got a Flex application (using 3.0) which has some custom context menus.  One thing we add is an "About..." entry which pops up an Alert with the application's version string and copyright information.  Unfortunately, Flex seems to have recently taken a dislike to our caption -- supplying "About" or "About..." leads to the menu item not appearing (with no errors or trace output) while supplying (apparently) any other caption makes things work.

We're pretty sure it stopped working with Flash Player 10.1.

Any clues as to why?

Answer (score 0):

About is probably a reserved word in the context menu.  You won't get any errors, but the menu option is just ignored.

Trying using `about&nbsp;` or `about_` or something similar.